# Algorithm for Array with 5 elements that when filled groups the elements

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, element

I'm trying to figure out a way to fill an int array with an n number of elements by adding them one by one. When every spot of the array is filled I want them to group in the first possible position and start over.

For example:

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

This is how the array looks empty.

If I want to add 2 elements it should look like this:

[1, 1, 0, 0, 0]

With 5 elements it looks like this:

[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

So far, so good. Now, on the sixth element addition I want this to happen:

[2, 0, 0, 0, 0]

And then for the next elements to fill  as before, except for the first spot that holds the group:

[2, 1, 0, 0, 0]

[2, 1, 1, 0, 0]

[2, 1, 1, 1, 0]

[2, 1, 1, 1, 1]

And then the next step should be:

[2, 2, 0, 0, 0] etc.

I hope I am clear as to what I'm looking for. Is there an algorithm for this? I searched and found nothing. Can someone create an algorithm for this?

My assignment is due on Sunday and I would really appreciate if you could help me find a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is finding minimum element, if it repeats we take first one. Then we increment it and all elements after min element become 0.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        next(arr);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}

static void next(int[] arr) {
    int idx = 0; //index of min element
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[idx] > arr[i]) {
            idx = i;
        }
    }
    Arrays.fill(arr, idx + 1, arr.length, 0);
    arr[idx]++;
}
```

After adding 15 elements:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[2, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[2, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[2, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 0, 0, 0]
[2, 2, 1, 0, 0]
[2, 2, 1, 1, 0]
[2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 2, 0, 0]
```